# While Loop Not working only creating 3 objects

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop inside a method that is supposed to create 24 dynamically created objects. However the loop creates 3 and then stops.

```
int test = 24;

while (placenum< test)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel name = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    FlowLayoutPanel data = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    FlowLayoutPanel pic = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    int sort = 0;

    while (sort == 0)
    {
        SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(first);
        first.Margin = new Padding(50, 50, 3, 50);
        first.Size = new Size(320, 320);
        first.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        first.Controls.Add(name);
        name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
        name.Margin = new Padding(0);
        first.Controls.Add(data);
        data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
        data.Margin = new Padding(0);
        first.Controls.Add(pic);
        pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
        pic.Margin = new Padding(0);
        sort = 1;
        placenum = placenum + 1;
    }

     while (sort == 1)
     {
         SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(two);
         two.Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 3, 50);
         two.Size = new Size(320, 320);
         two.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
         two.Controls.Add(name);
         name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
         name.Margin = new Padding(0);
         two.Controls.Add(data);
         data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
         data.Margin = new Padding(0);
         two.Controls.Add(pic);
         pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
         pic.Margin = new Padding(0);
         sort = 2;
         placenum = placenum + 1;
     }

     while (sort == 2)
     {
         SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(last);
         last.Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 10, 50);
         last.Size = new Size(320, 320);
         last.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
         last.Controls.Add(name);
         name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
         name.Margin = new Padding(0);
         last.Controls.Add(data);
         data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
         data.Margin = new Padding(0);
         last.Controls.Add(pic);
         pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
         pic.Margin = new Padding(0);
         sort = 0;
         placenum = placenum + 1;
     }
 };

 return null;
```

The `FlowLayoutPanel` called `Searchrdata` is the one that the other objects are supposed to be made but, it makes only 3 and stops.
[image: output]

Comment: You shouldn't be using `while` for this. A simple 8-count `for` loop that adds 3 controls each time would make far more sense. And it appears your logic keeps adding the same 3 objects to your controls, you should probably be adding new objects each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three variables named `first`, `two`, and `last`.  Presumably these are the controls you are trying to add.  The issue is you are adding the same instance of the three variables over and over again.  You should be creating a new instance of `first`, `two`, and `last` each time if you want a new one added each time.  Note that you are already doing this with `name`, `data`, and `pic`.

Also, as others have noted, you also don't need `while (sort == 1)` it should be `if (sort == 1)`.

Finally, note that if you ran your code through the debugger and stepped through, you would see that your loop is running the number of times you want, and you might have figured out what the real issue is.

Comment: Ok i will try and change the variables. I only changed the ifs to whiles when it did not work thinking that would solve it.

Comment: OMG You are a life saver. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` from the end of outer `while` loop. It causes termination of loop after 1 iteration. P.S it will create `3x24 = 72` total objects instead of 24.

A better solution will be :

```
for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel name = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    FlowLayoutPanel data = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    FlowLayoutPanel pic = new FlowLayoutPanel();

    SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(first);
    first.Margin = new Padding(50, 50, 3, 50);
    first.Size = new Size(320, 320);
    first.BackColor = Color.Azure;
    first.Controls.Add(name);
    name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    name.Margin = new Padding(0);
    first.Controls.Add(data);
    data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    data.Margin = new Padding(0);
    first.Controls.Add(pic);
    pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
    pic.Margin = new Padding(0);

    SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(two);
    two.Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 3, 50);
    two.Size = new Size(320, 320);
    two.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    two.Controls.Add(name);
    name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    name.Margin = new Padding(0);
    two.Controls.Add(data);
    data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    data.Margin = new Padding(0);
    two.Controls.Add(pic);
    pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
    pic.Margin = new Padding(0);

    SearchR.Searchrdata.Controls.Add(last);
    last.Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 10, 50);
    last.Size = new Size(320, 320);
    last.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
    last.Controls.Add(name);
    name.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    name.Margin = new Padding(0);
    last.Controls.Add(data);
    data.Size = new Size(320, 22);
    data.Margin = new Padding(0);
    last.Controls.Add(pic);
    pic.Size = new Size(320, 276);
    pic.Margin = new Padding(0);
    }



}

return null;
```

Comment: This isn't true. The extra `;` at that point in the code has no impact.

Comment: Also the inner whiles are unnecessary. All three blocks will be run on each loop. If you want to hit only one on each loop and cycle between the three, you should bring the declaration of sort outside the main while loop and use a switch...case construct instead.

Comment: Updated my answer. Down-voters please don't hurt my feelings. I was having a good day :)

Comment: There might be some other problem in your code. for example you are creating name, data, pic variables at ever iteration.

Comment: Sorry guys, i gave a striped down version. The amount of times it needs to run is not exactly 24. It gets the amount it needs to run it gets from a server that could be from 1 -anything. I put the three bits in while loops as well because if the server says run only once it will only run the first while loop. but if it says more than 3 it will continue the cycle.